# Regular expression pattern for String (SQL Select query)

Tags: java

I have to validate `SQL` query syntax given by user (as String) in java program using regular expression pattern. e.g user enter

```
Select name,address,detail from Student where detail='I m a Student'
```

What will be the regular expression pattern for this query ??

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to check.

Comment: Can these statements be arbitrary complex, e.g. include GROUP BY, HAVING, WITH, JOIN, Subselects, ...?